# Integrating an ADF application in SSO

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to do silent login (redirect) to an ADF application directly from the java post method by setting input parameters including username and password in a JSP. But seems like, this way doesn't work with ADF application as does work usually with JAVA applications. Currently I do see the ADF application page saying that

> Because of inactivity, your session has timed out and no longer active.

I do not have much idea how ADF application's login module internally works.
I'm looking for any insights on this or any idea why the above method cannot work with ADF application?

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://oraclefusionhelp.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-configure-adf-web-application-to.html) approach and see this works ,later modify SSO page mentioned in the blog to use your custom SSO

Comment: I guess, this is not what I am looking for. Firstly, I do not have any control over the ADF application which is actually an Oracle application. I just want that I should not see the login page of that Oracle (ADF) application. Once I login to my custom SSO and if I want to access the Oracle application directly from it using some link etc, then it should directly take me to the page with user logged in instead of showing login page of Oracle application. (NOTE : CREDENTIALS used for SSO would be same as of Oracle application). Please let me know if any more detail is required.